# .net 2010 error CS0433 when use user control

Tags: visual-studio-2010, user-controls

I have "Search" `User Control`.
When I Build My solution I get This Error :

Error:   ***error CS0433: The type 'UserControl_Search' exists in both '~\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\fssweb\40592537\9aa35db9\App_Web_xuubpve2.dll' and '~\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\fssweb\40592537\9aa35db9\App_Web_wrtemu0v.dll'***

can any people help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the temporary files from the location specified in the error

1)AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\fssweb\40592537\9aa35db9\App_Web_xuubpve2.dll
2)AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\fssweb\40592537\9aa35db9\App_Web_wrtemu0v.dll

Build the solution and run it again.

Comment: i delete this folders but the problem resolved for 1 time, in next build i get this error again

Comment: Check out the following links. They might help You.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/92461656-2d9f-4de5-ad3f-6d2310099370/the-type-xxxxascx-exists-in-both-cwindowsmicrosoftnetframeworkv2050727temporary-aspnet

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1249970.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found What maybe causes that, I have two `UserControls`:

1. `Search.ascx`
2. `NewSearch.ascx`

In code behind they have the same names:

```
public partial class UserControl_Search : System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

When I rename that in `NewSearch.ascx` to:

```
 public partial class UserControl_NewSearch : System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

This problem resolved!